QML MenuItem Icon does not turn gray when disabled
Ok. This is a minimal sample code of the problem.
If I specify any color for "item1"'s icon when the MenuItem is disabled the icon won't gray out.
So the question is if this is a QML bug or There is a way to evade the problem.
I have to use the transparent color because otherwise the icon(Which contains transparent pixels) will turn black.
import QtQuick 6.5
import QtQuick.Controls 6.5

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    width: 200
    height: 200

    state: "State1"

    Menu {
        id: menu
        title: "Menu"

        MenuItem {
            id: item1
            text: "Item 1"

            icon {
                source: "images/cam1.png"
                // The issue is here. removing this line will give the disabled effect on icon.
                color: "transparent"
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Press me")
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Connections {
            target: button
            onClicked: menu.open()
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: stateButton
        text: qsTr("Change state")
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 45
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Connections {
            target: stateButton
            onClicked: {
                if (rectangle.state === "State2")
                    rectangle.state = "State1"
                else
                    rectangle.state = "State2"
            }
        }
    }
    states: [
        State {
            name: "State1"

            PropertyChanges {
                target: item1
                enabled: false
            }

            PropertyChanges {
                target: subMenu
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "State2"
        }
    ]
}

I tried changing color when changing state to values other than "transparent" hoping the problem is with transparent value. But I found out specifying any color would cause the icon to not have disabled effect.
Edit:
If I add a submenu like this:
    Menu {
        id: menu
        title: "Menu"

        MenuItem {
            id: item1
            text: "Item 1"

            icon {
                source: "images/cam1.png"
                // The issue is here. removing this line will give the disabled effect on icon.
                color: "transparent"
            }
        }

        Menu {
            id: menu1
            title: "Menu 1"

            icon {
                source: "images/cam1.png"
                color: "transparent"
            }
        }
    }

Then 'menu1' Icon is perfectly grayed out when it is disabled. But the 'item1' icon won't.
Edit 2:
Now I see that this behavior can be varied based on application style. For clarification the style I am testing under is Basic style.

For this type of application, if you use a specially crafted SVG, you will be able to implement disabled icons by property binding icon.color to enabled as per below:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Menu {
        id: menu
        title: "Menu" 
        MenuItem {
            text: "Item 1"
            enabled: chk1.checked
            palette.windowText: enabled ? "red" : Qt.lighter("red", 1.5)
            icon.source: "images/cam1.svg"
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Item 2"
            enabled: chk2.checked
            palette.windowText: enabled ? "blue" : Qt.lighter("blue", 1.5)
            icon.source: "images/cam1.svg"
        }
    }
    Button { x: 10; y: 140; text: qsTr("Press me"); onClicked: menu.open() }
    CheckBox { id: chk1; x: 10; y: 200; text: qsTr("Enabled 1"); checked: true; onToggled: menu.open() }
    CheckBox { id: chk2; x: 10; y: 240; text: qsTr("Enabled 2"); checked: true; onToggled: menu.open()  }
}

// images/cam1.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="transparent" fill="black" d="
M 16 24
L 4 24
L 4 8
L 12 8
L 14 6
L 18 6
L 20 8
L 28 8
L 28 24
L 16 24
L 16 20
A 4 4 0 0 0 16 12
A 4 4 0 0 0 16 20
z" />
</svg>

You can Try it Online!
The tricks to crafting that SVG are:

The SVG is monochrome (i.e. must be uniformly in one color, because that color will be set later via icon.color)
The SVG must rely only on fill, it shouldn't rely on stroke
Build your object with closed polygons, e.g. path, circle, rectangle
For donut polygons, one must define the exterior in a clock-wise manner, but, the interior (or the hole) in an anti-clockwise manner

[EDIT]
I updated the solution to use the SystemPalette, i.e.
icon.color: enabled ? palette.text : palette.mid

[MORE EDIT]
Note that icon.color appears to be defaulting to palette.windowText. The menu item text color also appears to be following this color as well. So, if you set that color instead you be controlling both the menu item and icon color at the same time, i.e.
palette.windowText: enabled ? "red" : Qt.lighter("red", 1.5)


Erhmm.., Thanks for answering. But that is a hell of restrictions. I will try your answer and respond accordingly. But it could be nice if you pointed out based on what you sorted these restrictions out. Are these based on any documentation or reference?

@e1985t I found which SVGs work for me thru experience and trial-and-error. I rewrote the camera SVG making it easier to follow and edit in hope you can craft your own.

It is not a matter of using and SVG Stephan. If one is to use your approach of changing the icon color based on enabled property, Then I tried your approach with a monochrome PNG and PNG works as well. So more than using a workaround I wonder if there is any way to get the built-in disabled effect to work or not. Also notice I updated my question and mentioned the built-in disabled effect works for 'Menu' type(even with color set). But it does not work for MenuItem type. So what's the difference? Is it not a bug on QML side?

I updated my answer to explain how setting palette.windowText may give you an even better result than setting icon.color.

The reason that it doesn't work is because in the MenuItem.qml source code, it is probably already defining icon.color like this:
icon.color: enabled ? <normal color> : <disabled color>

So if you overwrite that property by saying icon.color: "transparent" then it loses that check for the enabled state. All you have to do is add it back in yourself, specifying what color you want for the disabled state. For example:
icon.color: enabled ? "transparent" : "#60000000"


So how you explain 'Menu' type's icon  being successfully enabled disabled even with icon.color set to "transparent"?

I don't understand the question because a Menu is not the same as a MenuItem, so the implementation can be completely different. Did you try my suggestion?

Look at the question where I added the edit title, you can see the QML code that contains a Menu Under which a MenuItem and another Menu(as a sub-menu) is added. My point is if I disable the sub-menu it successfully displays the disabled effect without any further effort. despite having color: "transparent" set for it. But the MenuItem requires the disabled state being handled to show the disabled effect. It is not about your or Stephens's workaround not working. The point is why Menu(the sub-menu) shows disabled effect with no further effort but MenuItem needs to be handled your way?
